# Survival analysis in R; creating interactive kaplan-meier plot in with plotly package

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, survival-analysis, ggplotly

I am generating kaplan-meier plots within R and I was wondering if there were a way to create an interactive kaplan-meier plot using the `plotly` package? Ideally, I would like to be able to trace the survival "line" using my mouse cursor with the `plotly` tooltip box telling me the group, the survival rate, and the time as well.

Here is an mock example of survival analysis that I would like to recreate within `plotly`:-

```
library(survival)
library(ranger)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggfortify)
library(plotly)
#------------
data(veteran)
head(veteran)

km_trt_fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ trt, data=veteran)
#using autoplot to create graph
autoplot(km_trt_fit)
```

[image]

But when I try to use `plotly`, I get this error:-

```
ggplotly(km_trt_fit)


#Error in UseMethod("ggplotly", p) : 
  #no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "survfit"
```

What would be the additional steps I need to take to get the `km_trt_fit` variable to be amenable to the `ggplotly` function? And would I be able to see within the tooltip the features which I have outlined above? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to extract the ggplot figure from a `ggsurvplot` object.

```
library(survminer)

p <- ggsurvplot(km_trt_fit)

ggplotly(p[[1]])
```

To obtain table data on events at different time points, you can work with `p[[3]]`.